# Computing number of block reads given relational algebra

Tags: database, database-design, relational-algebra

So I'm just starting to learn about query processing and such in databases and I'm having some trouble.  I don't really understand how to compute the minimum number of block reads given a relation and a query I guess you could say.  If anyone could help me out, it'd be much appreciated.  Here is an example that I'm working on:

- R1(A,B,C) A is a primary key and C is a foreign key to R2.C
- R2(C,D,E) C is a primary key
- R1 has 20,000 records, with 200 records per block. There is a primary B+-tree index on
  A with height h = 3
- R2 has 45,000 records, with 4,500 records per block. There is a primary B+-tree index
  on C with height hC = 3 and a secondary B+-tree index on D with height hD = 2.

Find the minimum number of block reads for each statement.  I can only hold one block of memory for each relation at a time.

- Where B=1(R1)
- Where C=1(R2)

I'm not looking for answers.  I'm looking for explanation of how to actually do it and guide me along the way.  Aka equations, etc. It's kind of difficult to find anything beneficial online at all.

Thank you.

Comment: This really belongs on Computer Science Stack Exchange: http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I will be moving it there then.